# How to save and get array of json? (Rails5 / MySQL)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, mysql-8.0

I would like to get age_list data like [{age: 20, num:2}, {age: 21, num: 1}, ...].

But I have a problem saving the array of json.

Now,

```
# age_list's db settings

def change
 add_column :customers, :age_list, :json, null: true
end
```

```
# get params

def customers_params
 params.require(:customers).permit(:male, :female, age_list:[:age, :num])
end
```

```
# saved age_list data in the database column
{
    "0": {
        "age": "20",
        "num": "1"
    },
    "1": {
        "age": "21",
        "num": "1"
    }
}
```

How can I save array of json like I want.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
# get params

def customers_params
     params.require(:customers).permit(:male, :female, age_list:[:age, :num]).tap do |whitelisted|
         whitelisted[:age_list] = params[:customer_group][:age_list].present? ? params[:customer_group][:age_list].values : null
end
```

then I can save as array of json below

```
[
    {
        "age": "20",
        "num": "1"
    },
    {
        "age": "21",
        "num": "1"
    }
]

or

null
```